# What are good ways to synchronize a file in a distributed system?

Tags: design-patterns, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Assume you have a file in S3 ( Amazon's storage service ). There are 10 machines which downloads this file from s3 and makes additive changes. Every one hour, the file on s3 has to be updated which should be the union of all the machine's file + the original file. This process continues ( 10 machines download the updated file and operate on it.)

How would you design a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might as well use S3 for the temporary file updates.

Use sub-buckets on S3 to store the temp files by hour and name the files by IP address or server name of the 10 machines.

On S3:

```
/bucket-name/master_file
/bucket-name/timestamp/server1_file
/bucket-name/timestamp/server2_file
...
/bucket-name/timestamp/server10_file
```

After an hour as long as 10 addition files are there, download them locally (using some read file method using whatever programming language you are using), concatenate or whatever you need to do and store the master_file out there again.

Use a cron job or similar to execute hourly.   One cron entry on each of the 10 machines to do what they need to do and one cron job on the master machine to union the files.  You can then delete the sub-buckets if you want or don't even have them in the first place (pluses and minuses there for monitoring and logging).

Comment: I was thinking of doing it with SQS.  This looks like a good approach too.  This might still have synchronization issues for my case as I need the updated file in each system after an hour...